# SQLite INNER JOIN with ATTACHed databases

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have two SQLite databases with identical table structures that I need to query using VB.Net, but I can figure out pretty much any syntax. I am trying to figure out how to build the query string? This query works correctly:

```
    sb = New StringBuilder("SELECT Master.Name, Master.ID, Master.StartDate, Master.Supervisor, Log.LogType, Log.LogComment FROM Master INNER JOIN Log ON Master.ID = Log.ID WHERE date(Log.LogDate) = '")
    sb.Append(calendarDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    sb.Append("' ORDER BY Master.Name;")
    c = New SQLiteCommand(sb.ToString, _Conn)
    Using dr As SQLiteDataReader = c.ExecuteReader
```

...

I can also "attach" the second database with the following:

```
    sb = New StringBuilder("ATTACH DATABASE '")
    sb.Append(outDBPath)
    sb.Append("' AS db2;")
    c = New SQLiteCommand(sb.ToString, _Conn)
    c.ExecuteNonQuery()
    c.Dispose()
```

My question is, what is the syntax to query both databases? Is this even possible? In the past I used a For... Next loop and just changed the connection from the first database to the second.

Comment: I realise this isn't your question, but you really want to avoid building queries like that by string appending. You really really really want a prepared statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html:

> Tables in an attached database can be referred to using the syntax
>   database-name.table-name. If the name of the table is unique across
>   all attached databases and the main and temp databases, then the
>   database-name prefix is not required. If two or more tables in
>   different databases have the same name and the database-name prefix is
>   not used on a table reference, then the table chosen is the one in the
>   database that was least recently attached.

So you use `db2.Master` to refer to the `Master` table in the attached database.

Comment: So, the syntax would be similar to SELECT db1.Master.Name from db1.Master INNER JOIN db1.Log on db1.Master.ID = db1.Log.ID, db2.Master.Name from db2.Master inner join db2.Log on db2.Master.ID = db2.Log.ID ?

Comment: Yep, it would be similar if you attach one file as `db1` and another as `db2`. And you can use `main.Master` for the database you opened at the very start (it's not required as unqualified `Master` means the same *if the table exists*, but you may prefer it just for consistency).

Comment: Whenever you have multiple columns in result set, I would recommend using table aliases, so it's `SELECT a.Name, ...a.something, b.anotherthing FROM db1.Master a INNER JOIN db2.log b WHERE a.MasterID = b.MasterID`